# Cómo puedo obtener un registro dependiendo del número de fila - SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Un saludo a toda la comunidad!

Tengo la siguiente consulta: Requiero obtener un solo registro dependiendo del número de fila, es decir, traer el registro de la fila 1, de la fila 2, y así sucesivamente.

Tengo la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
DECLARE @resultadoTabla TABLE(indice int, monto_queda numeric(12,2), saldo_a_restar numeric(12,2), diferencia numeric(12,2))

DECLARE @contador int = 1;
DECLARE @numeroEvaluar numeric(12,2); 

WHILE @contador <= @CantidadColumnas BEGIN 

    SET @numeroEvaluar = FLOOR(RAND()*(999-1)+1)
 
    INSERT INTO @resultadoTabla (indice, monto_queda, saldo_a_restar, diferencia) VALUES (@contador, @numeroEvaluar , @SumaTotal, @SumaTotal+@numeroEvaluar)

    SET @contador = @contador + 1
    SET @SumaTotal = @SumaTotal + @numeroEvaluar

END

SELECT * FROM @resultadoTabla RT
```

Lo que estoy haciendo acá es tomar con número aleatorio [`@numeroEvaluar`] que simula el valor que deseo tomar realmente, ese valor es el siguiente:

```
SELECT T.Saldo
FROM @Tabla T
WHERE T.OrdenDoc=1 AND (ISNULL(T.SaldoSol,0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(T.SaldoDolar,0) <> 0) 
        AND t.Cliente='ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK' AND YEAR(T.Emision) = 2021 AND MONTH(T.Emision) = 01
```

Sin embargo ahí me "jalaría" todos los `T.Saldo` y solo requiero el de la fila 1, luego el de la fila 2 y así... estaba pensando en hacer match con mi variable `@contador` que a la vez me sirve como índice en mi `@resultadoTabla`.

Leí que esto se puede resolver con el `ROW_NUMBER()` o el `LAG()`, pero no logro incluirlo en mi consulta de forma correcta; espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacer tu sistema más lento al insertar fila por fila? Mejor explica lo que quieres hacer y podemos idear una solución óptima.

Comment: Sí, sé que es más lento, es la primera solución que se me ocurrió. Trato de resolver esta para luego optimizar mi consulta; el punto que quiero lograr obtener ese `T.Saldo` dependiendo de la fila en la que se encuentre en lugar de mi variable local `@numeroEvaluar`, como te puedes dar cuenta, este es un aleatorio y en realidad el número que requiero es `T.Saldo`.

Comment: ¿Y cómo se supone que vas a ordenar las filas? Las tablas no tienen un orden establecido.

Comment: Si que pueden tener un orden... a ver, cuando yo hago un `INSERT INTO` en un stored procedure como el mío, el orden viene a ser el mismo siempre, no varía a menos que yo quiera que varíe, no sé si me dejo entender del todo. La cuestión es que sigo trabajando en mi problema, estoy haciendo pruebas con el `ROW_NUMBER()`; sigo sin llegar a una solución. Si no se me entendió mi problema bien, coméntame para poder editar mi pregunta.

Comment: Los puedes insertar en un orden, pero dentro de la tabla no existe un orden. Estás buscando solución al problema equivocado. Si planteas el problema real, podría orientarte en vez de que sigas tratando de atrapar tu sombra.

Comment: @LuisCazares Tal cual lo dices compañero, quisiera colocar un orden, es decir, ponerle índice a una tabla la cual no tiene; intenté hacerlo con `LAG` pero eso me trae el índice del registro anterior y ello no quiero lograr.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136895/discussion-between-luis-cazares-and-lsanchezo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en la discusión del chat, lo que necesitas es algo mucho más sencillo de lo que estás intentando hacer. Desde hace una década están disponibles funciones que permiten manejar sumas acumuladas. Dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo junto con datos de prueba.

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE(
    OrdenDoc int,
    SaldoSol decimal(18,4),
    SaldoDolar decimal(18,4),
    Cliente varchar(200),
    Emision date
)
INSERT INTO @Tabla
VALUES( 1,  652.60, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210104'),
      ( 1,  236.90, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210104'),
      ( 1,  150.00, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210107'),
      ( 2,   59.00, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210107'),
      ( 1,   20.00, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210108'),
      ( 1,  652.60, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210111'),
      ( 2,  233.20, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210111'),
      ( 1,   20.00, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210112'),
      ( 1, 1236.74, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210113'),
      ( 1,  500.32, 0, 'ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK', '20210115')

SELECT OrdenDoc,
    Cliente,
    Emision,
    SaldoSol,
    SaldoDolar,
    SUM( SaldoSol) OVER( PARTITION BY Cliente ORDER BY Emision, OrdenDoc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),
    SUM( SaldoSol) OVER( PARTITION BY Cliente ORDER BY Emision, OrdenDoc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
FROM @Tabla T
WHERE (ISNULL(T.SaldoSol,0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(T.SaldoDolar,0) <> 0) 
        AND t.Cliente='ABANTO PADILLA JOHNNY FRANK' AND YEAR(T.Emision) = 2021 AND MONTH(T.Emision) = 01;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, con base en el chat puedo dar fe de que tu ayuda me ha servidor, la respuesta a esta pregunta es algo largo y trataré de colocarla cuando me de tiempo. Una vez más, gracias, tu aporte fue muy necesario.